# Remove some text between tags from HTML file

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed

I have multiple HTML files, like this:

```
</HEAD><BODY><B> something <BR>bla bla bla  
<A  HREF=http://www.exemple.com>http://exemple.com</A> -  site bla   
bla bla bla (test n°15336) <BR><BR><BR><HR>
```

I want to make it like this:

```
</HEAD><BODY><B> something <BR> <BR><BR><BR><HR>
```

Nothing works: sed, grep, awk... any suggestions?

Comment: Read [ask] then [edit] your question to provide all the missing pieces.

Answer (score -1):

I am back to post the solution after long search 
first i need to parsing my html file so i have create a php code that finish this task very simple and useful

```
<?php

define('TEMPLATE', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test.html');
$template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE);
$st='';
$template = preg_replace('#(<\/A>).*?(<BR>)#is', $st, $template);
$template = preg_replace('#(<BR>).*?(<BR>)#is', $st, $template);
$file = 'output.html';
file_put_contents($file, $template);
?>
```

Et Voila!!!!!! XD
Thank you for the Reputation and thank you again for no Helping .